# HBase data export to S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hbase

I am trying to export HBase table(size-23TB) data to S3.
So while using HBase export and passing S3 credentials via jceks path
Command :

`hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export $tableName -D hadoop.security.provider.path=jceksPath -Dfs.s3a.proxy.host=proxy details -Dfs.s3a.proxy.port=80 $s3Path`

> Exception: NumberFormatException.

Please someone let me know how to pass jceks path in HBase export.

Comment: have you tried `$ export HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -D hadoop.security.credential.provider.path=<jceksPath>"`?

Comment: Throwing error : couldn't find or load main class hadoop.security.credential.provider.path
Do I need to add any jars?

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because the -D properties should be passed before the actual arguments:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export -D hadoop.security.provider.path=jceksPath -D fs.s3a.proxy.host=proxy details -D fs.s3a.proxy.port=80 $tableName $s3Path
```